# How to hide the actual file name when accessing files through Amazon CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

There is a S3 bucket with millions of MP3 files in them. Each music file along with its preview MP3 file is in a folder inside that bucket. For example for a given music:

/music/123456/file_master.mp3
/music/123456/file_preview.mp3

I want to let the end-users to have access to the preview file through CloudFront and its Web Streaming feature. So I have set up Cloud Front and so uses can click on a link which points to the file on CloudFront:

http://blahblah.cloudfont.net/music/123456/file_preview.mp3

It works perfect except that a user can grab the file URL, replace the _preview part with _master and then listen to the entire track.  Unfortunately moving the master file and preview file to two different locations is not an option because not only there are millions of them but also an ingestion system is constantly publishing the files with that structure.

Is there a way to hide the file name and/or file path? e.g. something like http://blahblah.cloudfront.net/music/123456/ABC would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think CloudFront supports the kind of URL-rewriting that you propose, but you might be able to solve your problem by adding a new Behavior for the CloudFront distribution and use the "Path Pattern" in that behavior to only match f.ex. "`*_preview.mp3`" and then use the behavior precedence to put that new behaviour in front of the default behavior of the distribution (behaviors are handled in sequential order with first match), and finally set the default behavior to have "Restrict Viewer Access" set to "Yes" while you set "Restricted Viewer Access" to "No" in the new behavior that then only matches "`*_preview.mp3`"

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern for more information in regards to the Path Pattern.